# Node JS Find all element's attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I would like to find each element's id   but I "each" doesnt work (there is no metode each...)
How can I return each element's ID?

```
   var libxmljs = require("libxmljs");
 var xml = ('/SomePath/filexmlxml');
   var xmlDoc2 = libxmljs.parseXmlString(xmlStr);
 fs.readFile(__dirname + '/filexml.xml', function (err, data) {


     var xmlStr = data.toString();
var id = xmlDoc2.get('Objects').get('Object').attr('id').value(); // It works and get the first element id = 'Title 1'


     xmlDoc2.get('Objects').get('Object').each(function () {
         var whatid = xmlDoc2.get('Objects').get('Object').attr('id').value();
         console.log('wasd: ' + whatid);  // Doesnt work - because of each.
     })  
 console.log('idss: ' + id); here I can see the only first's element's ID.
```

Comment: Edited ---> var xmlDoc2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmlDoc2.get('Objects') will return a [Node](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/wiki/Node) object. It doesn't have a each method. You can use [prevSibling](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/wiki/Node#nodeprevsibling), [nextSibling](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/wiki/Node#nodeprevsibling) methods to traverse the siblings of the nodes.

Or even better use [childNodes](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/wiki/Element#elementchildnodes) on the element.

```
var children = xmlDoc2.get('Objects').childNodes();

children.forEach(function (child) {
  var whatid = child.get('Object').attr('id').value();
  console.log('wasd: ' + whatid);
});
```

Comment: "cannot call method 'attr' of undefined"

Comment: @user3586498 remove `.get('Object')` and try again, paste the output `console.log(child)` if that doesn't work.

Comment: var children = xmlDoc2.get('Objects').childNodes();

     children.forEach(function (child) {
         var whatid = child.attr('id').value();
         console.log('wasd: ' + child);
     });

Cannot call method 'value' of null :/
Same with console.log(whatid)

Comment: @user3586498 OMG, you have to paste the output of `console.log(child)`, I need to know what `child` is.

Comment: Ok, It gives me wasd: Null </br>  wasd: id='SomeId'  wasd: Null </br>  wasd: id='SomeId2'

So it works... thx